# what's wrong with my profiles.xml?

Tags: maven-2

This is a portion of my `profiles.xml` for `mvn`:

```
<profilesXml>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <build>
        <plugins> .. </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

This is what `mvn` says:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: 
Unrecognised tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...</id>\n
        <build>... @32:20)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message is giving you the correct feedback here, you cannot specify a `<build/>` section in an **external profile**, you are only allowed to specify `<properties>`, `<pluginRepositories>`, and `<repositories>`.  From the [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> #### Profiles in external files
>
> Profiles specified in external files
>   (i.e in `settings.xml` or
>   `profiles.xml`) are not portable in
>   the strictest sense. Anything that
>   seems to stand a high chance of
>   changing the result of the build is
>   restricted to the inline profiles in
>   the POM. Things like repository lists
>   could simply be a proprietary
>   repository of approved artifacts, and
>   won't change the outcome of the build.
>   Therefore, you will only be able to
>   modify the `<repositories>` and
>   `<pluginRepositories>` sections, plus
>   an extra `<properties>` section.
>
> The `<properties>` section allows you
>   to specify free-form key-value pairs
>   which will be included in the
>   interpolation process for the POM.
>   This allows you to specify a plugin
>   configuration in the form of
>   `${profile.provided.path}`.

If your snippet is coming from a book, the book should be fixed.

Comment: Indeed, from a book, published by Sonatype. Ok, thanks for explanation, will fix my project (and a book :)

Comment: @FaZend.com: I guess the Maven guys changed "the rules" at some time (because *Better Builds with Maven* also mentions a snippet similar to the one from your question).

Comment: @FaZend.com: Feel free to upvote too by the way, always appreciated ;)

Comment: Not sure why you didn't get a +1. There you go

Answer (score 0):

You can not have <build> area in your profile. Only plugins etc. You can configure the plugins etc.

Comment: You will say you got the same message ? I can't believe...Did you try to make a minimal try with things like this: <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>appserverConfig</id>
      <properties>
        <appserver.home>/path/to/appserver</appserver.home>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

instead of your just to make everything else is working correct.