# How to include/exclude resources in maven war package

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

Within my MAVEN project I'm trying to build a war package with certain resources based on a profile (defined in my settings.xml).

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses Enable this line will remove compiled classes from package -->
            <!-- packagingExcludes>view/test/**,WEB-INF/classes/**</packagingExcludes Does not work -->
            <packagingExcludes>view/test/**</packagingExcludes>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>resources/</directory>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <!-- excludes><exclude>**</exclude></excludes Does not work -->
                    <includes>
                        <include>ehcache.xml</include>
                        <include>${include.files}</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
            <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

My `src/main/resources` folder is empty, so in my package there are no config files that are not expected. But when I move my `resources` folder into `src/main/resources` then the profiles are not working anymore and the package always contains all files from the `resources` folder.

How to alter my pom.xml so that `resources` folder can be moved into `src/main/resources` as to my understanding that is where you store resources like configuration files etc ('best-practice')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you can reorganize your resources in a way so that you can apply a filter to the resources and that most files are always present for every configuration.
Suppose you have a properties file that need different values for different configurations. You can substitute the value with a variable like this:

```
url=${url}
mode=${mode}
```

Now you can use profiles to set the values for the files that need to be filtered and the ones that need to be excluded entirely for that configuration:

```
<profile>
  <id>production</id> 
     <build>
         <resources>
             <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                 <filtering>true</filtering>                  
                 <excludes>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #1]</exclude>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #2]</exclude>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #3]</exclude>
                 </excludes>
             </resource>
         </resources>
     </build>      
     <properties>
         <url>www.something.com</url>
         <mode>production</mode>
     </properties>
 </profile>
 <profile>
     <id>development</id>
     <build>
         <resources>
             <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                 <filtering>true</filtering>                  
                 <excludes>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #1]</exclude>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #2]</exclude>
                     <exclude>[non-resource file #3]</exclude>
                 </excludes>
             </resource>
         </resources>
     </build>      
     <properties>
         <url>localhost:8080/something</url>
         <mode>development</mode>
     </properties>
 </profile>
```

Finally you can delete the webResources tag in your maven-war-plugin. It wil pick up src/main/resources now because it's a configured resource.

Comment: Henry thank you for your answer, unfortunately when listing the exclude files they still appear in the war package.

Comment: Did remove the entire webResources tag in the maven-war-plugin.

Comment: [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...<profile>\r\n      <build>... @35:14)  @ D:\Users\IE329745\.m2\settings.xml, line 35, column 14
[WARNING]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351238/whats-wrong-with-my-profiles-xml -  you cannot specify a <build/> section in an external profile, you are only allowed to specify <properties>, <pluginRepositories>, and <repositories>.

Comment: project specific settings belong inside the project, so you could move the profile tags to your project pom.xml